# "The multi-part identifier could not be bound" SQL Server UPDATE command with joins

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an issue with an UPDATE command where I get the error

> The multi-part identifier "Day_settings.temp" could not be bound.

when trying to access a column value from a left join. When selecting, it works fine.

For example:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Animals 
LEFT JOIN Day_settings ON Animals.fk_day_id = Day_settings.id 
LEFT JOIN Night_settings ON Animals.fk_night_id = Night_settings.id
```

[image]

That works as expected. It also works when getting the value, like so:

```
SELECT Day_settings.temp, Night_settings.temp 
FROM Animals 
LEFT JOIN Day_settings ON Animals.fk_day_id = Day_settings.id 
LEFT JOIN Night_settings ON Animals.fk_night_id = Night_settings.id
```

[image]

The issue arrives when updating. I have tried fixing this by reading other stackoverflow questions, and none of the solutions work. Either using `dbo.tablename` or writing the selector after each JOIN statement has no effect.

The command is as follows:

```
 UPDATE Animals  
 SET Animals.title = @title,  
     Animals.is_active = @is_active,  
     Day_settings.temp = @day_settings_temp,  
     Day_settings.humid = @day_settings_humid,  
     Day_settings.light = @day_settings_light,  
     Day_settings.time = @day_settings_time,  
     Night_settings.temp = @night_settings_temp,  
     Night_settings.humid = @night_settings_humid,  
     Night_settings.light = @night_settings_light,  
     Night_settings.time = @night_settings_time  
 FROM Animals  
 LEFT JOIN Day_settings ON Animals.fk_day_id = Day_settings.id  
 LEFT JOIN Night_settings ON Animals.fk_night_id = Night_settings.id  
 WHERE Animals.id = @id
```

It seems to be following the order and syntax of all the examples I found online.

Any help would be very appreciated, I am truly lost.

Comment: SQL Server does not allow updating multiple tables in a single `UPDATE` -- well, you could create a view and an update trigger on the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only update 1 table per statement (unless you having triggers enabled). The start of you `UPDATE` says so:

```
UPDATE Animals SET
```

If you are not updating the joining fields or fields that are used on filtering conditions (or updating expressions), you can repeat the same join to update each table on different `UPDATE` statements:

```
UPDATE Animals  
 SET  
 title = @title,  -- You can omit the table alias here, as it's already mentioned right after the "UPDATE"
 is_active = @is_active
 FROM Animals  
 LEFT JOIN Day_settings ON Animals.fk_day_id = Day_settings.id  
 LEFT JOIN Night_settings ON Animals.fk_night_id = Night_settings.id  
 WHERE Animals.id = @id


 UPDATE Day_settings  
 SET  
 temp = @day_settings_temp,  
 humid = @day_settings_humid,  
 light = @day_settings_light,  
 time = @day_settings_time
 FROM Animals  
 LEFT JOIN Day_settings ON Animals.fk_day_id = Day_settings.id  
 LEFT JOIN Night_settings ON Animals.fk_night_id = Night_settings.id  
 WHERE Animals.id = @id

 UPDATE Night_settings  
 SET  
 temp = @night_settings_temp,  
 humid = @night_settings_humid,  
 light = @night_settings_light,  
 time = @night_settings_time  
 FROM Animals  
 LEFT JOIN Day_settings ON Animals.fk_day_id = Day_settings.id  
 LEFT JOIN Night_settings ON Animals.fk_night_id = Night_settings.id  
 WHERE Animals.id = @id
```

Since this seems like a transactional operation, you might want to ensure all 3 updates are correctly done, or none of them. Wrap the updates with a `TRANSACTION` and make sure to either `COMMIT` if OK or `ROLLBACK` if not. This is a simple transaction handling example:

```
BEGIN TRY

    BEGIN TRANSACTION

        UPDATE Table1 SET ....

        UPDATE Table2 SET ....

        UPDATE Table3 SET ....

    COMMIT

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH

    DECLARE @ErrorMessage VARCHAR(MAX) = ERROR_MESSAGE()

    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
        ROLLBACK

    RAISERROR(@ErrorMessage, 15, 1)

END CATCH
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to update the 3 tables in same time ?

I think you can only update tables 1 by 1

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/eab6e48d-d22a-4e1f-add6-aaf3b47bdd84/how-to-update-multiple-tables-in-sql-server-2008-?forum=transactsql

Answer (score 1):

You can only update one table at a time.  You seem to want:

```
UPDATE a
    SET title = @title,  
        is_active = @is_active
    FROM Animals a
    WHERE a.id = @id;

UPDATE ds  
    SET temp = @day_settings_temp,  
        humid = @day_settings_humid,  
        light = @day_settings_light,  
        time = @day_settings_time
   FROM Animals a JOIN
        Day_settings ds
        ON a.fk_day_id = ds.id  
   WHERE Animals.id = @id;

UPDATE ns  
    SET temp = @night_settings_temp,  
        humid = @night_settings_humid,  
        light = @night_settings_light,  
        time = @night_settings_time  
    FROM Animals a JOIN 
         Night_settings ns
        ON a.fk_night_id = ns.id  
    WHERE a.id = @id;
```

Notes:

- You can wrap these in a transaction if you want them all to take effect "at the same time".
- Table aliases make the query easier to write and to read.
- I removed the aliases in the `SET`.  They are allowed, but because only one table can be updated, I think that might be confusing.
- `LEFT JOIN`s are not necessary. You need a matching row in the second table to do the update.